# Support lower Versions in 10 SDK

Tags: blackberry, minimumosversion

I am developing a small application on Blackberry 10 SDK. I want my app to be available on OS Version 6,7 and 10.

Now that i am using SDK 10 how can i support OS version 6 and 7 for the same app.

What do I need to do in that. Are there any image changes for that versions?

Comment: if you using native SDK, its not possible to do. you have to use HTML5

Comment: What do i need to do for that ?

Answer (score 1):

"BlackBerry 10" and "BlackBerry 7, 6, and older" are different platforms.

HTML5/JavaScript applications can be compatible between BB 10 and older BB devices. But it is source code compatibility, it is not binary code compatibility.

You will need at least two compiled versions of your HTML5/JavaScript. One - for BB10, another for BB7 and older devices.

Get WebWorks for BB7 and older devices here:

http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/#smartphones

WebWorks for BB10 is available here:

http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/#blackberry10